# Bundle install command hits the rubygem sources twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Since last couple of months, i see that executing the "**bundle install**" command for a rails application, source(s) mentioned in gemfile is requested twice when it is supposed to request only once per source mentioned in gemfile.

Can anyone tell me why it is happening and suggest a workaround for it?

Comment: Are you talking about these lines?
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..

Comment: @basgys...yes exactly..that is what i am talking about.

Comment: There's an open issue for this on [github](http://bit.ly/ZPGO5o).

Answer (score 1):

In fact bundler does not hit rubygems twice, or at least not for the same reason.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
```

If you look at the queries performed during a "bundle update", here is what you got :

```
https://rubygems.org:443
http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=airbrake,aws-sdk
http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=json,activesupport,builder
http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=climate_control,rubinius-actor
http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=term-ansicolor,gherkin
http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=little-plugger,loquacious
http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=bones-rcov,bones-rubyforge
http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=systemu
http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=restclient,spicycode-rcov
```

*I intentionally shortened the URLs for the sake of readability*

If you enter this URL in your browser

```
http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies.json?gems=airbrake
```

*As you may have noticed, I added the .json extension to have a json output, because the default format is binary*

You will see something like this

```
[
    {
        "name":"airbrake",
        "number":"3.1.8",
        "platform":"ruby",
        "dependencies":[
            ["json",">= 0"],
            ["activesupport",">= 0"],
            ["builder",">= 0"]
        ]
    },
    ... (content removed)
]
```

This response tell us that the airbrake gem depends on json, activesupport and builder. So bundler needs to ask rubygems for more informations about these 3 gems. If you look at the second query above, this is exactly what it does.

```
http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=json,activesupport,builder
```

This process will take place until all dependencies are resolved. That's why the number of dots may changed depending on the number of "iterations" to resolve all dependencies.

However, I must admit that the reason why the message is shown twice remains unclear. Furthermore, the number of dots (10) does not correspond exactly to the number of queries (9)... I need to investigate a little bit more for that.

Comment: @basgys.. Thanks for the quick info..Will be curious to know more about it and in the meantime will try to look over it.